# Laravel: applying different filters on same query (optimization)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have to make one query to the database which returns a lot of lines (line 1). I was hoping that I could make this query only once and then apply various filters on it without accessing the database again. Something like this:

```
$finishedTrips = Auth::user()->trips()->whereNotNull('distance');

$transport = Config::get('transport');

foreach($transport as $key => $value) {
    $sum = $finishedTrips->where('transport', '=', $value['id'])->sum('distance');
}
```

This does not work and I've spent an hour realizing I actually need to do this to get it working:

```
$transport = Config::get('transport');

foreach($transport as $key => $value) {
    $sum = Auth::user()->trips()->whereNotNull('distance')->where('transport', '=', $value['id'])->sum('distance');
}
```

But I now have four potentially heavy queries instead of one. Is there a way to fix my first example? Should I use caching?

Comment: Have you looked at the `filter()` function at all on your collection?  It just takes a callback and returns a collection of all your items that make it through the callback.

Comment: No, I've only seen it mentioned once or twice in my research. I'll give it a try right now.

Comment: Okay, I've never used it before but I was curious and I think I have some idea of what's going on if you need help.  I think it should work for you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to make only one query to get all the results and then filter the results.

```
$finishedTrips = Auth::user()->trips()->whereNotNull('distance')->get();
```

Now `$finishedTrips` is an instance of [Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Collection.html) which has a method [filter()](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html#_filter) that you can use to filter the results

```
$transports = Config::get('transport');

foreach($transports as $transport) {

    $filteredList = $finishedTrips->filter(function ($t) use($transport) {
        return $t->transport == $transport['id'];
    });

    $sum = array_sum($filteredList->lists('distance'));
}
```

But this is a really bad approach. Whay you should use instead is one single query that groups by `transport` and sums `distance`.

```
// Code not tested but you get the idea
Trips::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->groupBy('transport')->sum('distance');
```

This achieves the same with one single line of code.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I had completely forgotten about this SQL feature.